# How can I prove by induction that $n^2+n+3$ is always odd?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I have the function $P(n)=n^2+n+3$, and I have to prove by induction that it is always odd. Firstly, I proved that $P(0)=3$. Now I have to prove that P(n+1) is also odd.

So far, my hypothesis is that $n^2+n+3$ is odd, and my thesis is that $(n+1)^2+(n+1)+3$ is also odd, but I'm stuck as I can't find a way to demonstrate it.

Comment: **Hint** $ $ Show $\,f(n+1)-f(n)\,$ is even, so $\,f(n+1)\,$ has the same parity as $\,f(n)\ $

Comment: PS if you know mod arithmetic you can rephrase the above as $\bmod 2\!:\ \color{#c00}{f(n+1)\equiv f(n)}\,$ and use this to show by induction that $\,f(n)\equiv f(0)\ [\equiv 1],\,$ i.e. an $\color{#c00}{\rm unchanging}$ discrete function is *constant* so $\equiv f(0)$ $\qquad\ $ $\qquad$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(n+1)^2+(n+1)+3=n^2+2n+1+n+1+3=n^2+n+3+2(n+1)$, since by hypothesis $n^2+n+3$ is odd, you deduce that $(n+1)^2+(n+1)+3$ is odd since it is the sum of an odd and an even number.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Expand your expression and use the fact that $n^2+n+3$ is even.

**Bonus:** You can solve the problem without induction: notice that $n^2+n+3=n(n+1)+3$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach. First, consider that $n = 2k$
\begin{align*}
n^{2} + n + 3 = (2k)^{2} + 2k + 3 = 4k^{2} + 2k + 3 = 2(2k^{2} + k + 1) + 1
\end{align*}
which is clearly odd. Analogously, for $n = 2k + 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
n^{2} + n + 3 = (2k+1)^{2} + 2k + 1 + 3 = 4k^{2} + 6k + 5 = 2(2k^{2} + 3k + 2) + 1
\end{align*}
which is obviously odd as well.